# How to increase contours precision?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am working on a project using OpenCV. I need to precisely crop out some objects from HD photos.
I'm using a quad tree to cut my photos in pieces and then I calculate the homogeneity of each quad to determine if a piece of the object is in the quad.
I apply some filters as Canny with different thresholds depending on the homogeneity of the quad.
I hope this description is understandable.

This algorithm works for certain kinds of objects but I'm stuck with some others.
Here some example of my problems: I would like a way to flatten my contours.
The first screenshot is a after using the canny filter and a floodfill. The second is the final mask result.

http://pastebin.com/91Pgrd2D

---

To achieve this result, I use `cvFindContours()` so I have the contours but I can't find a way to handle them like I want.

Comment: What is the problem with the contours that you have? You want to smooth them more?

Comment: @AdrianPopovici: kind of, I would like them to marry the curve from my object without having all the artefacts. Here it's the original piece: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/ex5gl.jpg/

Comment: You could run some filters on the B&W image before finding the contours, for example a Gaussian filter and then a threshold, that would smooth a little the contour but probably it would not fit the exact object in all the points. Another thing you could do with the contours is use AproxPoly and then apply a spline or something.

Comment: @AdrianPopovici: Thank you for your help, I used ApproxPoly but I give me too "squary" result even and with a spline afterwards, I lost too much informations. I'm looking for a way to approximate a curve instead of a polygone such as: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/821/ex6a.jpg/ to http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/269/ex7f.jpg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could use some kind of an average filter to approximate the curve and then use AproxPoly with a small gradient to smooth it.
Here is a similar method:

```
void AverageFilter(CvSeq * contour, int buff_length)
{
    int n = contour->total, i, j;
    if (n > buff_length)
    {
        CvPoint2D32f* pnt;
        float* sampleX = new float[buff_length];
        float* sampleY = new float[buff_length];

        pnt = (CvPoint2D32f*)cvGetSeqElem(contour, 0);
        for (i = 0; i < buff_length; i++)
        {
            if (i >= buff_length / 2)
            {
                pnt = (CvPoint2D32f*)cvGetSeqElem(contour, i + 1 - buff_length / 2 );
            }
            sampleX[i] = pnt->x;
            sampleY[i] = pnt->y;
        }

        float sumX = 0, sumY = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            pnt = (CvPoint2D32f*)cvGetSeqElem(contour, i);
            for (j = 0; j < buff_length; j++)
            {
                sumX += sampleX[j];
                sumY += sampleY[j];
            }
            pnt->x = sumX / buff_length;
            pnt->y = sumY / buff_length;
            for (j = 0; j < buff_length - 1; j++)
                {
                    sampleX[j] = sampleX[j+1];
                    sampleY[j] = sampleY[j+1];
                }
            if (i <= (n - buff_length / 2))
            {
                pnt = (CvPoint2D32f*)cvGetSeqElem(contour, i + buff_length / 2 + 1);
                sampleX[buff_length - 1] = pnt->x;
                sampleY[buff_length - 1] = pnt->y;
            }
            sumX = 0;
            sumY = 0;
        }
        delete[] sampleX;
        delete[] sampleY;
    }
}
```

You give it the contour and the size of the buffer of points that you want to do the average on.
If you think the contour is too thick because some of the averaged points are bundled together too close, then that's where Aproxpoly comes in because it reduces the number of points.
But choose an appropriate gradient so you don't make it too edgy.

```
srcSeq = cvApproxPoly(srcSeq,sizeof(CvContour),storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, x, 1);
```

Play around with 'x' to see how you get better results.

Comment: Thank it's exactly what I needed. But it makes weird stuff for every slice I use. More buff_lenght is high more the "lines" are strong. http://imageshack.us/f/831/seqs.png/ I'm working on it but if you know directly where it comes from it would help :)

Comment: Well, buff_length is how many points you want to include for the average of the current point, also it should be odd(13,15,17,19...), so for the buff_length of 13, each point will be recalculated from the average of the 6 previous points, itself and the next 6 points. If you have the contours obtained with CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE you will have more points so you get a better average. After that you could use AproxPoly with a small value parameter like 1-2

Comment: @Adrien: Thank you for your edit and, it works better with odd numbers, my bad :)