# Edge Smoothing and filling inner contours in opencv with iOS

Tags: ios, image, opencv, masking, smoothing

I am trying to tan human skin with different intensity with help of opencv. I have already identified human skin and changing color tone of those pixels. But it is not smooth.

[image: ScreenShot 1]

Top left - original image
Top right - saturation channel of original image
Bottom left - Gray scale mask identifying locations of skin on original image
Bottom right - result image with color tone changed of pixels located in mask.

Now my problem is that, in mask image some gap is left because of variation on color tone or brightness in original image. And that is why those portion is missed in result image. Can anyone tell me how can I fill the small gaps in mask image?

[image: Gaps in mask image]

Another if someone can help me out for smoothing only edges of my tanned mask will help me a lot. See the reference image below,

[image: Sharp tanned mask edge]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about?

```
morphologyEx(grey,grey,MORPH_CLOSE,getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size(7,7)));
```

although the silhouette gets merged for the left hand

[image: simple]

edit:slightly more involved

```
Mat tmp=grey.clone();
morphologyEx(tmp,tmp,MORPH_GRADIENT,getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size(3,3)));
bitwise_not(tmp,tmp);
Mat smallholes=Mat::zeros(tmp.size(), CV_8UC1);
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(tmp,contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{       
    double area = contourArea(Mat(contours[i]));
    if(area<100)
        drawContours(smallholes, contours, i, 255, -1);
}
Mat done;
bitwise_or(grey,smallholes,done);
morphologyEx(done,done,MORPH_CLOSE,getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size(3,3)));
```

[image: long]

Comment: This worked greatly!! Thank you very much for this. Currently I am trying to smooth the sharp edge after tanning as I have mentioned in my second screen shot. Any suggestions for the same?

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644996/how-to-increase-contours-precision? i havent personally tried it yet but it seems to have worked for at least one person

Comment: @AnjumShrimali what did you do for edge smoothning?